# How to properly add file as a link to rmarkdown shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have shiny app where one of the tabs shows my rmarkdown document. Inside this rmarkdown document I want to add a link to the file that user can download or review.

Simple code for shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(includeMarkdown("rmarkdown.Rmd")), 
    server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

rmarkdown file:

```
Here is the [someFile](someFile.pdf).
```

This gives 
[image]

however once you click this link it says file not found.

[image].

Even though file exist (save folder as shiny app which runs on shiny server) and you can reach the file if you right click "save link as" (on Chrome).

What I want is to click on the file link and open or download it.

**SOLVED**

I moved the file to www folder. Now it works properly.

Comment: Where is that mentioned www folder?. I have the same issue as you but there is no www folder

Comment: Inside shiny application folder create a folder called www That should work :)

Comment: Thanks Kipras, tried that but no success so far

Comment: Share your app somehow(dropbox, git ...). I will have a look.

Comment: Kipras , here steps for a minimal reproducible example:  open Rstudio server > new Rmarkdown file > add this code to last chunk: dev.off() ; png("www/myplot.png") ; plot(pressure) ; dev.off()     , include a Rmarkdown link to generated plot after last chunk, then knit and point a browser to your Rmd and try to download plot.

Comment: `Here is the [myplot](www/myplot.png) ` - this line worked for me.

Comment: But for me, it works when knitting inside Rstudio, not when pointing user with browser to app.

Comment: When I am running app on a server previous line doesn't work, but `[myplot](myplot.png)` does.

Comment: not for me, sorry